# How can I change the Border Corner Radius of my ToggleButton when ToggleButton is checked?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox, controltemplate

I got a `ComboBox` which has a `Style` where a `ToggleButton` is on top. I gave it a `CornerRadius` and I want that when I check the `ToggleButton` and my `ComboBox` is opening the bottom `CornerRadius` should change. My `ComboBox` style:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#D4D4E1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="18"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ToggleButton Name="PART_EditableTextBox"            
                                  Style="{StaticResource MyButton}"                  
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                             Padding="5,0,0,0" BorderThickness="0"
                             Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                        <ToggleButton.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10 0 0 10"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ToggleButton.Resources>
                    </ToggleButton>

                    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1" Margin="0" Background="#2C2F33"
                                 Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Style="{StaticResource MyButton}"
                                 Focusable="False" BorderThickness="0" 
                                 IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                 ClickMode="Press">
                        <Path Grid.Column="1" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                              Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"
                              Fill="LightBlue" />
                        <ToggleButton.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0 10 10 0"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ToggleButton.Resources>
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite"
                                  Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                  ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                    <Popup Name="Popup"
                           Placement="Bottom"
                           IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                           AllowsTransparency="True" 
                           Focusable="False"
                           PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <Grid Name="DropDown"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
                              MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                              MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                            <Border 
                                x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                BorderThickness="0" 
                                CornerRadius="0 0 7 7" 
                                Background="#2E3136"
                                BorderBrush="Black"/>
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

My `ToggleButton` style:

```
<Style x:Key="MyButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#2C2F33" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Border Name="border" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Black" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="" Property="" Value="0.8" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It looks like this when the `ComboBox` is closed:

[image: Closed ComboBox with all rounded corners.]

It looks like this when it is open:

[image: Open ComboBox with all rounded corners and its popup with rounded corners only at the bottom and sharp corners at the top.]

However, I am not able to change the bottom `CornerRadius` to get this type of look like Google:

[image: Open ComboBox with rounded corners only at the top and at the bottom of its popup. The area between the ComboBox and the Popup looks contiguous.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `DataTrigger`s to your `ToggleButton` styles that change the `CornerRadius` depending on the [`IsDropDownOpen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.combobox.isdropdownopen?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) property of the `ComboBox`, which indicates if the `Popup` is shown.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="True">
   <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10 0 0 0" />
</DataTrigger>
```

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="True">
   <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0 10 0 0" />
</DataTrigger>
```

The `RelativeSource` is used to refer to the parent `ComboBox` as source. This is the complete code:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#D4D4E1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="18"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ToggleButton Name="PART_EditableTextBox"            
                                  Style="{StaticResource MyButton}"                  
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                             Padding="5,0,0,0" BorderThickness="0"
                             Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                        <ToggleButton.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10 0 0 10"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="True">
                                      <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10 0 0 0" />
                                   </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </ToggleButton.Resources>
                    </ToggleButton>

                    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1" Margin="0" Background="#2C2F33"
                                 Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Style="{StaticResource MyButton}"
                                 Focusable="False" BorderThickness="0" 
                                 IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                 ClickMode="Press">
                        <Path Grid.Column="1" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                              Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"
                              Fill="LightBlue" />
                        <ToggleButton.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0 10 10 0"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="True">
                                      <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0 10 0 0" />
                                   </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </ToggleButton.Resources>
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite"
                                  Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                  ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                    <Popup Name="Popup"
                           Placement="Bottom"
                           IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                           AllowsTransparency="True" 
                           Focusable="False"
                           PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <Grid Name="DropDown"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
                              MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                              MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                            <Border 
                                x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                BorderThickness="0" 
                                CornerRadius="0 0 7 7" 
                                Background="#2E3136"
                                BorderBrush="Black"/>
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The closed and opened state look like this:

[image: Closed and opened state of the ComboBox with different corner radii.]